# C# - Randomizing lines of a text box

Tags: c#, list, random, textbox

Say i have a text box with the following content:

```
Word
Entry
List
Sentry
```

Each on their own line. How can i randomize them, to appear something like this(on button click):

```
Entry
List
Sentry
Word
```

Or any random combination. Now note, i have something like 100,000 separate lines for some of the files i import. I need the to be randomized on button click. Thanks!

What im going to do is have 2 multi-line text boxes next to each other, the user can randomize each list, then a separate button will combine both lists into one file, delimited by a colon(:). Thanks a ton!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: Split into a list. Shuffle the list. Join back into a string delimited by newline characters.

Comment: Did you try googling "c# random"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "Randomize", think "[Shuffle](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle)":

```
void Shuffle<T>(IList<T> items)
{
    // creating a new object here for demo purposes
    // Really, the same object should be re-used across method calls
    var random = new Random(); 

    for (int i = items.Count; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        T tmp = items[j];
        items[j] = items[i - 1];
        items[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

The Windows Forms textbox has a helpful `Lines` property to make this easy to use:

```
 string[] lines = MyTextBox.Lines;
 Shuffle(lines);
```

Comment: You could mention the Fisher-Yates algorithm directly in your answer.